# Constraint for two binary vectors to be different

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, integer-programming, binary-variable, logical-constraints

If I have a matrix $A$ of binary variables $a_{i,j}$, $1 \le i \le n$, $1 \le j \le m$, how can I enforce in an Integer Linear Program with binary variables, the condition that every two columns must be different?

I know from [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/12118/148736) how to do it for a single row (two elements), for example requiring that the XOR of the two values be equal to $1$, but how to do it on the full column? Is making the OR over all the rows the only option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *encode* the column to be a single binary number, the first column is either larger or less than the second column. Define binary variables $b_{j, j'}$ forall $1 \leq j < j' \leq m$.
$$
\sum_{i} 2^i(a_{i, j} - a_{i, j'}) \geq 1 - 2^{n+1} b_{j, j'}\\
\sum_{i} 2^i(a_{i, j} - a_{i, j'}) \leq -1 + 2^{n+1}(1 - b_{j, j'})
$$

This model has less auxiliary variables but many large coefficients.

Comment: I think the subscripts are transposed. This seems to enforce a difference between *rows* $i$ and $i'.$

Answer (score 11):

Let binary decision variable $x_{ijk}$ indicate whether columns $j$ and $k$ (with $j<k$) differ in row $i$, and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_i x_{ijk} &\ge 1 &&\text{for $j<k$} \tag1\label1\\
x_{ijk} \le a_{ij} + a_{ik} &\le 2-x_{ijk} &&\text{for all $i$ and $j<k$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} enforces $\bigvee_i x_{ijk}$ for column pair $(j,k)$.  Constraint \eqref{2} enforces $x_{ijk} \implies a_{ij} + a_{ik} = 1$.  Because $a$ is binary, $a_{ij} + a_{ik} = 1$ is equivalent to $a_{ij} \not= a_{ik}$.

Answer (score 2):

This is an "alldifferent" constraint.  In addition to the two approaches already described, I'll describe two more.

## Binary encoding

Yet another way is to use a binary encoding of a location that differs, rather than a one-hot encoding as in [RobPratt's answer](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/9350/2415).  In particular, we'll have binary decision variables $x_{jk\ell}$, where $x_{jk\lg n} \cdots x_{jk1} x_{jk0}$ is intended to be interpreted as the binary representation of a row $i$ such that $a_{i,j} \ne a_{i,k}$.  To ensure this representation is valid, we add the constraint

$$(x_{jk0} \ne i_0) \lor (x_{jk1} \ne i_1) \lor \dots \lor (x_{jk\lg n} \ne i_{\lg n})$$

for every $i,j,k$ such that $a_{i,j} = a_{i,k}$.  Here I write $i_\ell$ for the $\ell$th bit of the binary representation of $i$.  The above constraint can be expressed as a linear inequality as

$$1 \le \sum_{i_\ell=0} x_{jk\ell} + \sum_{i_\ell=1} (1-x_{jk\ell}),$$

where the first sum ranges over $\ell$ such that $i_\ell=0$ and the second sum ranges over $\ell$ such that $i_\ell=1$, and we have one linear inequality per $i,j,k$ such that $a_{i,j}=a_{i,k}$ and $j<k$.

This approach uses about $0.5 m^2 \lg n$ binary variables and $0.5 m^2 n$ linear inequalities.  Compare to RobPratt's answer, which uses $m^2 n$ binary variables and $m^2 n$ linear inequalities.  So, this approach is more concise than RobPratt's answer: it uses significantly fewer variables and $2\times$ fewer inequalities.  However, it is possible that it might play less well with solvers (e.g., because randomized rounding is less likely to be effective).

## Sorting networks

Another approach is to build a [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) to sort the $m$ columns, then after they are put into sorted order, add constraints to ensure that each adjacent pair of columns are different.

You can build a sorting network to sort the $m$ columns using $O(\log^2 m)$ layers, where each layer has $O(m)$ comparators.  You can express each comparator in ILP using $O(n)$ binary variables and $O(n)$ linear inequalities.  This leads to a sorting network that uses $O(mn\log^2 m)$ variables and inequalities.  The final check that each adjacent pair of columns are different can be done with $O(mn)$ variables and inequalities.

So, in total, this gives a solution that encodes your problem as an ILP instance with $O(mn \log^2 m)$ variables and inequalities.  For small $m,n$, this is probably worse than the other approaches, but for large values of $m$, it is possible that this might work better.